# JAVA - Unmarshal XML doc to object

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

my question is similar to others asked before, but the fact is that I wasn't able to solve my problem yet. 
I have a XML document which I need to convert (unmarshal) to an object, and I'm doing that using JAXB annotations. So far, so good, but there is one property I can't get the value from.
Let me code instead of talking.

My Java object:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Product {
    private String date_upd;
    private MetaDescription meta_description;

    //------------Static classes for sub nodes------------------
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    static class MetaDescription{
        private List<Language> language ;
    }

    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    static class Language{
        @XmlAttribute(name="id")
        private String id;
        @XmlValue
        private String language = null;
        void setLanguage(String language){
            this.language = language;
        }
        String getLanguage(){
            return this.language;
        }
    }


     public String getDate_upd() {
        return date_upd;
    }

    /**
     * @param date_upd the date_upd to set
     */
    @XmlElement
    public void setDate_upd(String date_upd) {
        this.date_upd = date_upd;
    }

    /**
     * @return the meta_description
     */
    public MetaDescription getMeta_description() {
        return meta_description;
    }

    /**
     * @param meta_description the meta_description to set
     */
    @XmlElement
    public void setMeta_description(MetaDescription meta_description) {
        this.meta_description = meta_description;
    }

}
```

And my XML document has the following fragment:

```
<product>
  <date_upd>
    <![CDATA[2013-12-06 18:03:59]]>
  </date_upd>
  <meta_description>
    <language id="1" xlink:href="http://demo1.it2care.com/shop/api/languages/1">
      <![CDATA[product1]]>
    </language>
    <language id="2" xlink:href="http://demo1.it2care.com/shop/api/languages/2">
      <![CDATA[produto1]]>
    </language>
  </meta_description>
</product>
```

It has a lot more properties, but only these are relevant. 'date_upd' is getting unmarshalled correctly, but I can't solve it for 'meta_description'. I get a List of 'Language' objects inside the 'MetaDescription' field, but I can't get the value for a 'Language', although I get the 'id' attr from the 'language' node. 
For the presented XML example, 'meta_description' is a List which has 2 elements. On both list elements 'ID' is correctly filled but I get "" from the 'language', instead of 'product1'.

Any hints guys? Thank very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I got it! I was getting "" for the language, since my nodes had CDATA elements inside them. For a reason I'm still trying to figure out, the unmarshaller wasn't getting into these nodes, therefore returning an empty string.
I solved the problem at it's origin. When converting a XML string from the server to a XML Document I added the following fragment:

```
//Create a Document factory
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
//Line I added
factory.setCoalescing(true); //remove all CDATA wrappers
```

This solved me the problem, using the construction I posted initially. 
Hope this helps!